# exit a for statement and write stream into a new file in python

Tags: python, file, for-loop, stream

I am a python beginner, I try to get an webradio and save the stream inside a file. I want to flush the content after a while (only keep 1 hour of stream for exemple). So I don't write all the stream in one file, I try to store the stream in many files (output_1.bin for one minute, output_2.bin for the next one...)

But I am not able to correctly exit from the "for". exit() isn't made to this purpose ?

```
def download_file(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    i = 1
    while True:
        local_filename = "output_"+str(i)+".bin"
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                    f.write(chunk)
                    i = i+1
                    print("iteration",i,"and modulo result :",i % 10,"\n")
                    if i % 10 == 0:
                        exit()
        f.close()
        print("Am I out of the for ?")
    return local_filename

download_file('http://direct.franceinfo.fr/live/franceinfo-lofi.mp3')
```

Comment: `exit()` exits the process.  You probably want `break`.

Comment: I think you may be looking for the break command not exit()

Comment: By the way, you should not use `exit()` in a script even to exit the process (it is meant for interactive use only), you should use `sys.exit()` instead.

Comment: ...and your `while` loop has no exit condition either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit()` quits a python application. What you want is `break`.

Comment: Wahouuu express answer ! It's perfect... Sorry I was not able to find the right command. It seams I need to wait 15 minutes to accept your answer

Comment: and after that `f.close()` will crash on "operation on closed file" because with block already closed the file.

Comment: True, you don't need `f.close()` since you opened the file in the `with` block anyway.